# Hibernate query to get existing conversations between 2 users

Tags: mysql, hibernate, messaging

I have 2 tables to denote a conversation, I think it is a pretty standard format.

```
CREATE TABLE conversation (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '',
  last_modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE conversation_user (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  conversation_id INT NOT NULL,
  conversation_is_visible BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  unread BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, conversation_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_conversation_user_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_conversation_user_conversation_id FOREIGN KEY (conversation_id) REFERENCES conversation (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I want to be able to check if a conversation exists between 2 users (I don't care about starting a new conversation for more than 2 users if it already exists).

I can't seem to be able to write a query to select the conversation with just the 2 given users in it, and no more.
I then want to convert the query into a hibernate query.

For example if i had the following data:

```
select * from conversation;
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
| id | name                   | last_modified       |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | test conversation 1    | 2017-02-25 15:39:01 |
|  2 | test conversation 2    | 2017-02-26 16:29:14 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+

select * from conversation_user;
+---------+-----------------+-------------------------+--------+
| user_id | conversation_id | conversation_is_visible | unread |
+---------+-----------------+-------------------------+--------+
|       1 |               1 |                       1 |      0 |
|       1 |               2 |                       1 |      0 |
|       2 |               1 |                       1 |      1 |
|       2 |               2 |                       1 |      0 |
|       3 |               2 |                       1 |      0 |
+---------+-----------------+-------------------------+--------+
```

The query should when searching for a conversation between user 1 and user 2 only have conversation 1 show up, as conversation 2 has user 3 in it aswell.

I've tried the following query, but that shows up both conversations, so not sure how to restrict it to conversations just containing those users...

```
SELECT * FROM conversation 
LEFT JOIN conversation_user ON conversation.id = conversation_user.conversation_id 
WHERE user_id IN (1,2);
```

I could use this query in hibernate and then check the set of conversation users in the conversation to make sure the conversation only contains the 2 given users, but was wondering if there was a more efficient approach

Comment: some sample data and expected output example would be great.

Comment: And your best effort so far

Comment: @Utsav have updated the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/587e4/5

```
SELECT t1.user_id,
       t1.conversation_id,
       t1.conversation_is_visible,
       t1.unread
FROM conversation_user t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT user_id,conversation_id
   FROM conversation_user WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
) t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
AND t1.conversation_id=t2.conversation_id
WHERE t2.conversation_id IS NOT NULL;
```

If you just want `conversation_id` then use `distinct t1.conversation_id` in `select` clause.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this query would still return both conversations however.. i have posted an answer based on yours that got me the right results

Answer (score 0):

Based on Utsav's answer, the following query got the results i was after.

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.conversation_id, t1.conversation_is_visible, t1.unread 
FROM conversation_user t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM conversation_user 
    GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    ) t2 
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.conversation_id=t2.conversation_id 
WHERE t1.user_id IN (1,2) AND t2.conversation_id IS NOT NULL;
```

still not sure how to convert this to a query in hibernate but its a start